# How to create a new variable based on the values of a number of existing variables simultaneously in R?

Tags: r, string, variables

I'm working on a dataset in R and want to create a new variable based on the values of variable dx1. Here's my code.

```
Data1$AMI <- Data1$dx1 %in% c("I21.0", "I21.1", "I21.2", "I21.3", 
                              "I21.4", "I21.9", "I21.A")
```

My question is how to assign the value of AMI based on a number of variables, say dx1 to dx25? In this dataset, dx1 refers to primary diagnosis, dx2 refers to second diagnosis, and so on. Any of them contain the specific diagnosis code (("I21.0", "I21.1", "I21.2", "I21.3", "I21.4", "I21.9", "I21.A") ) will be assigned a value “1”.

If dx1 %in% c("I21.0", "I21.1", "I21.2")  or dx2 %in% c("I21.0", "I21.1", "I21.2") or dx3 %in% c("I21.0", "I21.1", "I21.2”), we want the AMI column show “1”.

Comment: What do you mean simultaneously? It would be easier if you can share a minimal example of your data and expected outcome.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear. In the dataset, dx1 refers to primary diagnosis, dx2 refers to second diagnosis, and so on. Any of them contain the specific diagnosis code (("I21.0", "I21.1", "I21.2", "I21.3", "I21.4", "I21.9", "I21.A") ) will be assigned a value “1”.

Comment: The [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) answer to this issue is to store / reshape your data so you have diagnoses running down the page with the `id` columns repeated against each diagnosis. Then you can literally use an `%in%` statement to flag diagnoses, before aggregating your data back to `id` level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question; is this what you want to do?

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Create fake data
dx <- list()
for (i in 1:25){
  dx[[i]] <- c(paste("I",
                     round(rnorm(n = 50, mean = 21, sd = 5), 1),
                     sep = ""))
}

name_list <- paste("dx", 1:25, sep = "")
Data1 <- as.data.frame(dx, col.names = name_list)

# Create a variable called "AMI" to count the occurrences of values:
# "I21.0","I21.1","I21.2","I21.3","I21.4","I21.9"
Data2 <- Data1 %>% 
 mutate(AMI = rowSums(
   sapply(select(., starts_with("dx")),
          function(x) grepl(pattern = paste(c("I21.0","I21.1","I21.2","I21.3","I21.4","I21.9"),
                                            collapse = "|"), x)
   ))
 )
Data2
```

### Edit

Here is how to get the new variable "AMI" to show the value "1" for any row when one or more variables from the list 'dx1:dx25' has a value from the list '"I21.0","I21.1","I21.2","I21.3","I21.4","I21.9"':

```
Data2 <- Data1 %>% 
 mutate(AMI = ifelse(rowSums(
   sapply(select(., starts_with("dx")),
          function(x) grepl(pattern = paste(c("I21.0","I21.1","I21.2","I21.3","I21.4","I21.9"),
                                            collapse = "|"), x)
   )) > 0, 1, 0)
 )
Data2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Sorry, I should have made it clear. In the dataset, dx1 refers to primary diagnosis, dx2 refers to second diagnosis, and so on. Any of them contain the specific diagnosis code (("I21.0", "I21.1", "I21.2", "I21.3", "I21.4", "I21.9", "I21.A") ) will be assigned a value “1”.

Comment: The new variable "AMI" can only hold a single value... If dx1 == "I21.0" and dx2 == "I21.0", what should the AMI column show? 2? or do you want to replace the value "I21.0" in both dx1 and dx2 with the value 1? Can you please edit your question to clarify, showing the expected output

Comment: Sure. Thank you for pointing it out. If dx1 %in% c("I21.0", "I21.1", "I21.2")  or dx2 %in% c("I21.0", "I21.1", "I21.2") or dx3 %in% c("I21.0", "I21.1", "I21.2”), AMI column show “1”. 

To keep the original data, we won’t replace value "I21.0" in both dx1 and dx2 with the value 1. Just create a new variable to reflect the diagnosis.

Comment: Updated to suit - does this achieve what you want?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I wanted! Very helpful. Thank you so much!